# Symbolic tensor value error when using Lambda layer in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

```
ValueError: Layer lambda_47 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'tuple'>. Full input: [(<tf.Tensor 'lambda_45/Slice:0' shape=(110000, 1, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_46/Slice:0' shape=(110000, 1, 128) dtype=float32>)]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors
```

I have been trying to implement tensorflow operations with a keras frontend in a model definition. I am having a problem creating a transformation layer that allows for weight updates. I have read that Keras' Lambda function is the key to doing this, but I ran into this error.

Here is my code:

```
### CONTROL VARIABLES (i.e. user input parameters)
dropout_rate = 0.5 
batch_size = 128
nb_epochs = 40
#with tf.device('/gpu:0'):


### MODEL CREATION
X_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_1')
# Input
X_i = Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(x, [0,0,0], [110000,1,128]))(X_input)                               # Slicing out inphase column
X_q = Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(x, [0,1,0], [110000,1,128]))(X_input)                               # Slicing out quadrature column
X_mag = Lambda(lambda x_i, x_q: tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.add(tf.math.square(x_i), tf.math.square(x_q))))((X_i, X_q))     # Acquiring magnitude of IQ
## THE SOURCE OF THE ERROR IS THE LINE ABOVE ^
## ITS USING TENSORFLOW OPERATORS TO FIND ABSOLUTE VALUE
X_phase = Lambda(lambda x_i, x_q: tf.math.atan2(x_i, x_q))((X_i, X_q))                                               # Acquiring phase of IQ
X = Concatenate(axis=1)([X_mag, X_phase])                                                           # Combining into two column (magnitude,phase) tensor
X = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(2,8), padding='same',data_format='channels_last')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)
X = Dropout(dropout_rate)(X)
X = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(1,8), padding='same',data_format='channels_last')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)
X = Dropout(dropout_rate)(X)
X = Flatten()(X)
X = Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu')(X)
X = Dropout(dropout_rate)(X)
X = Dense(len(classes), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(X)
X = Activation('softmax', name = 'labels')(X)

model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = X)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])
```

Full stack trace error:

```
The shape of x is  (220000, 2, 128)
(110000, 2, 128) [2, 128]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    278             try:
--> 279                 K.is_keras_tensor(x)
    280             except ValueError:

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in is_keras_tensor(x)
    473         raise ValueError('Unexpectedly found an instance of type `' +
--> 474                          str(type(x)) + '`. '
    475                          'Expected a symbolic tensor instance.')

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'tuple'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-dba00eef4193> in <module>()
    108 X_i = Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(x, [0,0,0], [110000,1,128]))(X_input)                                # Slicing out inphase column
    109 X_q = Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(x, [0,1,0], [110000,1,128]))(X_input)                                # Slicing out quadrature column
--> 110 X_mag = Lambda(lambda x_i, x_q: tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.add(tf.math.square(x_i), tf.math.square(x_q))))((X_i, X_q))     # Acquiring magnitude of IQ
    111 X_phase = Lambda(lambda x_i, x_q: tf.math.atan2(x_i, x_q))((X_i, X_q))                                               # Acquiring phase of IQ
    112 X = Concatenate(axis=1)([X_mag, X_phase])                                                           # Combining into two column (magnitude,phase) tensor

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    412                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    413                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 414                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    415 
    416                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    283                                  'Received type: ' +
    284                                  str(type(x)) + '. Full input: ' +
--> 285                                  str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
    286                                  'should be tensors.')
    287 

ValueError: Layer lambda_47 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'tuple'>. Full input: [(<tf.Tensor 'lambda_45/Slice:0' shape=(110000, 1, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_46/Slice:0' shape=(110000, 1, 128) dtype=float32>)]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

So the error is occurring on the "X_mag = Lambda" line. I have searched all related stack overflow posts, and none seem to account for the embedded use of tf operations here. Please help me resolve this issue!

Its really stumped me over the past two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass **tuples** to layers as their input. Instead you should use **lists**. Also, as a result, the `lambda` function in a `Lambda` layer accepts **only one** input argument, i.e. a list, which you can access its element using index:

```
X_mag = Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.sqrt(
             tf.math.add(tf.math.square(x[0]), tf.math.square(x[1]))))([X_i, X_q])     # Acquiring magnitude of IQ

X_phase = Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.atan2(x[0], x[1]))([X_i, X_q])   # Acquiring phase of IQ
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to train my model with the above code, but for some reason got an error "NameError: name 'tf' is not defined" immediately after finishing training. Was trained in google colab, using dataset DeepSig Dataset: RadioML 2016.10A from https://www.deepsig.io/datasets

Comment: If you can't reproduce, please let me know! Thanks either way!

Comment: @Mr.T Are you saving and re-loading your model after training is finished?

Comment: Yes the 'tf is not defined error' had to do with code I forgot I messed with for a tensorflow graph. Thank you for your help!